# Attribute error after pickle

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, attributeerror

First I followed an iris tutorial and it worked great! the program ran fine and did everything it was supposed to do. Then I started working on a pickle tutorial to pickle data then open it again ... then everything went crazy. Now I have a pycache folder in my code folder that wasn't there and I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'

So far I have tried completely wiping scipy, numpy, sklearn, and pandas from my computer and reinstalling. Then I tried disabling rapport (I'm on an Ubuntu machine) because a part of the bug long error code kept talking about it.

Below is the program I ran that I think caused this.

```
 Save Model Using Pickle
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pickle
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv"
names = ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class']
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]
test_size = 0.33
seed = 7
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
# Fit the model on 33%
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
# save the model to disk
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to strip out some of the narrative (it's just a bit distracting from what your problem is) and give us a bit more information about what steps led up to your issue, what your set up looks like, your exact error messages, etc. It might help to look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post the stack trace and if possible the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation I realized I saved the code as pickle.py on my computer (in the same folder that the pycache was appearing). I changed it to pickle1.py and now everything works. Lesson learned don't name code after modules...

Answer (score 0):

I might guess that your numpy installation somehow got stepped on. Maybe try "pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy" in your command line?

Or maybe it's a line that says "numpy.dtype" somewhere is being used wrong. You'd have to share at least that line of code to see that though.

Just wild guesses without having your entire setup.